# Trying to echo a column from a table that is displayed via for each

Tags: javascript, php

I am using this table and trying to echo the "branchid" in an alert 
[image: 1]

There are two tables:

**orders_address.php**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once('orders_address.vc.php');
?>
```

Here is a snippet of my for each table, the 'branchid' and the assign button is only the concern here'

```
                    <td>
                      <a href="order_address.vc.php<?php echo '?branchid='.$rowAddress['branchid']; ?>">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn button-color-blue font-color-white full_width" name="assign" value="ASSIGN">
                      </a>
                    </td>

                    <td class="table-text-center">
                      <?php
                          echo($rowAddress['branchid']);
                      ?>
                    </td>
```

**orders_address.vc.php**

Below is the code when the button is clicked

```
  if (isset($_POST['assign']) && $_POST['assign'] == 'ASSIGN')
  {
    $branchid = $_GET ['branchid'];
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$branchid');</script>";
    }
```

Currently I am getting an undefined index and the alert box is empty. the $_GET ['branchid'] does not seem to retrieve the column I want.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You may need to use simply `$_REQUEST['your_inedex']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td>
    <?php 
        $branchid = isset($rowAddress['branchid']) ? $rowAddress['branchid'] : 0; 
    ?>
    <form method="POST" action="order_address.vc.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="branchid" value="<?php echo $branchid ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="assign" value="ASSIGN" />
        <input type="submit" value="ASSIGN" class="btn button-color-blue font-color-white full_width" />
    </form>
</td>
<td class="table-text-center">
  <?php echo $branchid; ?>
</td>


orders_address.vc.php:

if(isset($_POST['assign']) && $_POST['assign'] === 'ASSIGN') {     
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'alert('.$_POST['branchid'].')';
    echo '</script>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you have a form submit button wrapped around an anchor tag. When the submit tag is clicked I honestly don't know which one takes precedence, the anchor tag or the form submission.

Assuming that you have the table wrapped in an HTML form and a POST request is made. I suggest adding the `branchid` as the value of the submit button. Ex:

```
 <input type="submit" class="..." name="assign" value="<?=$rowAddress['branchid']?>">
```

In receiving end you can then get `branchid` from `$_POST['assign']`

```
if (! empty($_POST['assign']))
{
    $branchid = $_POST['assign'];
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$branchid');</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have `$_GET['branchid']` in `POST` handle

```
if (isset($_POST['assign']) && $_POST['assign'] == 'ASSIGN') ...
```

But you send it as normal `GET` a href link so condition with `POST` is never true.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['assign']) && $_POST['assign'] == 'ASSIGN'){
$branchid = $_GET ['branchid'];
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$branchid');</script>";
}
```

HTML should be as below:

```
<form action="order_address.vc.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="branchid" value="<?php echo $branchid ?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="assign" value="ASSIGN" />
</form>
```